# Render Image F12 shows non-existing plane after Boolean modifier

Tags: rendering

I created a hole in the top of my door using a Cube and a Boolean modifier.
I show you several screenshots of my Blender in various Viewuport shadings, where you can see right through the hole, into the blue colored hallway with a lamp in it.

When I press Render image F12, this hole is closed with a plane of some sort.

I do not understand this, in all other 3D views there is no face at all, no plane, it's a hole, why is there a plane visible in the final ender Image?
I updated with an extra image in Solid View where I put the normals view on.
This could explain something?

Thank you!
Regards.

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Final F12 render Image shows plane:

[image]

Normals view on:

[image]

Comment: I guess you didn't restrict render on boolean object

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to delete the older question, I deleted the older post right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
I solved it, the plane which blocked the view did exist in my scene.
I created it a little while ago and hidden it from 3Dview, but not in Render Image F12.
Also it was located nearly on the bottom of a long list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting your question clearly.
1. make sure you have really applied the boolean modifier on your object (lamp).
If you did and you still get a non-boolean operation in your lamp, additional objects may have been created. 
2. Go to your outliner and click on your modeled lamp. See if there are any children under the main object.
3. If there are (and surely there will), just click the EYE icon and the CAMERA icon to the right of the outliner icons. Those will disable render view and display view.
Try rendering now.

It is quite possible you have a duplicated object as a result of the boolean operation. But instead you´re seeing the END result object. At render time the original boolean object gets also rendered.

If you find this is the answer, please click the check mark icon to the left of this post, and thank you for your consideration as the answer voting it up.

BFCT_Schiller